# How to send array of arrays as data in ajax

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
var data = ["id","userId",[{item:[1,2]},{item:[1,2]}]]
```

Currently i'm sending this data as

```
var data = ["id","userId","[{\"item\":[\"1\",\"2\"]},{\"item\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}"]]
by using JSON.stringify()
```

Now when i receive this data for parsing this i have to split it across [{ ,}]
and then splitting at }, to run a for loop on the array elements

```
vars args = args[2].toString().split("[{")[1].split("}]")[0];
args = '{' +args;
var list = args.split("},");
list.forEach((elem)=>{
   elem = elem + '}';
   elem = JSON.parse(elem);
   var items = elem.item;
});
```

otherwise with JSON.parse() i'm getting unexpected token error.I tried using JSON.stringify() and then parsing it but i got the same error.

How do i parse this data correctly on the server side?

Comment: Why are you sending it as a string? Just send `data` untouched.

Comment: If is do that..then on the server i get data as an empty array like ["id","userId",[]] or something like ths ["id","userId","/u000"]

Comment: _“Or should i send data in other format?”_ - in the comments on the existing answer you are saying you can’t change anything about this, because the server-side part that receives this was already written - now which one is it, actually?

Comment: @misorude Actually the server side first checks whether the data recieved is an array or not..and then that data is send to a backend code where i'm parsing the data recieved..The server side is already written but the backend where this data is getting used is written by me.So my question was is there any other proper format to send the 3rd argument which is an array

Answer (score 0):

I think you can format your data a bit better, so it's a valid JSON.
example:

```
     {
       "id": "userId",
       "data": [
                {
                  "item": [1,2]
                },
                {
                   "item": [1,2]
                }
              ]
      }
```

Comment: I have to send it as an array only.The server code has been written like that.I have no other option

Comment: Then just put the object in an array `[{ ... }]` like so : [https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=670a69d7ec1d4bc79f71dc137e58c5f5](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=670a69d7ec1d4bc79f71dc137e58c5f5)

Comment: i have to send it that way.Only the 3rd index should be an array..i can't modify that

Comment: `var arr = JSON.stringify([{item:[1,2]},{item:[1,2]}]);

var data = ["id","userId", arr];`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send a stringified Array instead of the original Array [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is the way to go.

Your code will look something like this:

```js
const data = ["id", "userId", [{item: [1, 2]}, {item: [1, 2]}]];

// check for each item in data if its an array and convert it to a JSON string
data.forEach((d, i) => {
  if (Array.isArray(d)) {
    data[i] = JSON.stringify(d);
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

This will be a more sustainable solution because the script checks and converts every item on the list. So if the list changes in the future this script still converts it successfully.

Comment: What your code is doing is the same as how i'm sending my data..i'm myself using JSON.stringify() before sending that array which is giving me this output var data = ["id","userId","[{\"item\":[\"1\",\"2\"]},{\"item\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}"]]..my question is how do i handle this stringified array on the server side...because JSON.parse() gives me error on this array